# Retrieving file and forwarding to another API is causing error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, axios, serverless-framework

I am retrieving a file from an S3 bucket and then forwarding it to another API. It's causing the following error:

```
DataCloneError: function httpAdapter(config) {
  return new Promise(function dispatchHttpRequest(resolvePromise, rejectPromise)...<omitted>...
} could not be cloned.
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (file:///D:/Dev/beep/node_modules/serverless-offline/src/lambda/handler-runner/worker-thread-runner/workerThreadHelper.js:24:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

The code used is here:

```
module.exports.fileUpload = async (event) => {
    const bodyForm = JSON.parse(event.body);
    const s3 = getS3Client();

    const getObjectCommand = new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket: 'bucket-name',
        Key: path.parse(bodyForm.name).name
    });

    const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(s3, getObjectCommand);
    const response = await axios.get(signedUrl, { responseType: 'stream' });
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', response.data, bodyForm.edf_name);
    await axios.post('https://api-url', form).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens (most probably) because your `form` object has methods in it (like your `append` method), and methods cannot be serialised.

You have two options here:

1. The hacky way, forcing a serializable form:

```js
const serializableForm = JSON.parse(JSON.stringyfy(form));
await axios.post('https://api-url', serializableForm).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
```

2. The better way, in which you map what form fields you need in your request

```js
const serializableForm = {
  foo: form.foo,
  bar: form.bar
  // ...
};
await axios.post('https://api-url', serializableForm).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
```